# Как сделать рейтинг пользователей по счету

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть задача сделать рейтинг пользователей, по их счету (тот у кого больше очков - на 1 месте, у кого меньше - на последнем) через цикл с jquery

```
var scores = [userScore1, userScore2, userScore3, userScore4...]
var scoresRank = [userScore1, userScore2, userScore3, userScore4...]

var maxScore=Math.max.apply(Math, scoresRank)

var rank = 1
var rankPosition = 0
var userPosition
var userIndex
var arrleng=0

while (arrleng!=scores.length) {

        for (var i = scoresRank.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {



            if (scoresRank[i]==maxScore) {
                $('.user .userRank').eq(i).text(rank)
                rank++
                arrleng++
                scoresRank.splice(i, 1)
                if (scoresRank!=-1) {
                    maxScore=Math.max.apply(Math, scoresRank)
                }
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: В коде вы по очереди находите максимальные числа в массиве и записываете в некий блок `'.user .userRank'` их номер "по рейтингу" максимальных очков. А в чем собстно вопрос-то?

Comment: Т.е. можно ли свести вопрос к этому: Прилетел массив `[15, 7, 12, 64]` — 64 на 1-м месте, 15 на втором... на выходе должно стать `[2, 4, 3, 1]` ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const scores = [
    { user: "Ivan", score: 22 },
    { user: "Petr", score: 11 },
    { user: "Vasya", score: 20 },
];
[...scores].sort((a,b)=>b.score-a.score).forEach((item,pos)=>{
    const div = document.createElement("DIV")
    div.innerHTML = `${pos}. ${item.user}`
    document.documentElement.appendChild(div)
})
```